# ASP.net Web Api layer between domain and what is serialized

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In standard .NET MVC we have our Domain classes and we have ModelView classes. Now, with ASP.Net Web API I suppose there is no need for ModelView classes (since we are returning data) but should we return (serialized) Domain classes directly or there is a need for something in between?

```
// Domain class
public class User {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
  public string LastName {get;set;}
}

// inter class
public class ProductModel {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
  public string LastName {get;set;}
  public string FullName {get {return String.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);}}
}

// Controller V1 returns Product    
public class UserController : ApiController 
{
   public Product GetProduct(int id) {...}
}

// Controller V2 returns ProductModel     
public class UserController : ApiController 
{    
   public ProductModel GetProduct(int id) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exposing your domain model in a API is rarely a good idea.

If you are the only one who will be consuming the API and you can be sure that you will deploy updates to the client and the server at exactly the same frequency, then you may be able to take this shortcut, however, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Sample? What to use? Model classes mapped from domain classes or...?